# How to use sessions with connect-mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, mongoose, database

In docs of `connect-mongo` I read only about it set up, nothing more. How to define sessions? How to read?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/MYDATABASE');

app.use(session({
    secret: "SOME_SECRET_KEY",
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

Okay, I set up. If I have

```
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
// If user authorized
// I want to define a session.user = req.body.user 
// And then I want to read this value in other my site pages
});
```

How I can define user login and some other data to session?

How I can read this values?

Where this session will store in MongoDB? Or I need to define not only way to *MYDATABASE* and to *MYDATABASE/sessionstore* ?

Must I to generate secret or this must be a one defined string?

Answer (score 3):

1. Reading from and writing to the session is done through the `req.session` object: `req.session.userId = req.body.userId`
2. The session data will be stored in a collection called `sessions` by
   default.
3. [About the session secret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18565873/1402230)

Comment: I think we wanted to know how to access those database-stored sessions